# Is it secure to rely on the data in a lambda context authorizer claims?

Tags: aws

I am working on lambda authorization and I learned that there are generally two options.

Either use the default authorizer on the API gateway level, which will do all the heavy lifting (validate the tokens), or write a custom authorizer, which will require me to implement all the logic including all the token validations, which I would like to avoid if possible. I don't want to write such code, I want to use something that is time proven and tested.

My question is, **is it considered secure to write code in my lambda (e.g. python decorator) that will do authorization based on the data in the lambda context.authorizer.claims?** 
assuming of course all I need is there (e.g. cognito:groups, cognito:username, etc.)

can I treat the authorizer data in the context as solid (passed the security validation)?

Comment: Are you asking about authentication or authorization? i.e verify if the token is authenticate, or verifying if the token has the right scope for the resource in question?

Comment: @keithRozario I want to add to my API GW a Cognito User Pool authorizer that will validate the tokens that users got from the google login that is in place. then I would like to add an extra layer of authorization without having to do the token validations myself. so I figured I could write a decorator for the lambda and use the info that can be read from the context (or event if I do custom mapping of the authorization details), then act upon them (e.g. allow access to certain users).  I wanted to make sure that you can count on the authorization data that you get in the lambda arguments